# Pattern to filter by elements on list?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is the query I would like to make

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-() WHERE (n.id in {ids}) AND r.resources CONTAINS {posibleValues}
```

Is this legal?

r.resources is a `list` of `strings`

I'm doing this from Java and right now I'm doing string building and putting the `posibleValues` in `OR` ex: `r.resources CONTAINS x OR r.resources CONTAINS y`... etc which is awful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet is probably what you are looking for:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-() 
WHERE (n.id IN {ids}) AND ANY(x IN r.resources WHERE x IN {possibleValues})
```

It assumes the parameters `{ids}` and `{possibleValues}` are collections.